# How do I play a midi file in assembly x86 DOSBox tasm?

Tags: assembly, x86, midi, tasm, dosbox

I am doing a project and I need to have background music. I'm using DOSBox emulator and tasm.

I tried using the 330h and 331h ports, but I couldn't make any music come out.

Comment: AFIAK, x86 has never had a dedicated MIDI port. The MIDI ports were on sound cards or on dedicated cards. For DOSBox, you probably need to configure a sound card beside the MIDI emulation mode. Then enable the MIDI port through the card IO interface and put it in the desired mode. [Here's the SoundBlaster programming manual](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/readings/hardware/SoundBlaster.pdf). The MPU-401 is always used as a UART. A [mcve] and the exact format of the MIDI file would help.

Comment: there is a site here that helped me at the beginning but i couldn't understand how to play the midi file from it [link](http://midi.teragonaudio.com/tech/mpu.htm)

Comment: I guess your other question got closed because the task is too large for a single answer. Parsing and playback of MIDI data are separate things, and assembly is the wrong language for that. And somebody who is hardcore enough to use assembly is supposed to be able to do his own research.

Answer (score 2):

You have to [configure DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Configuration:MIDI) to emulate the MPU-401 in UART mode, and to route the MIDI data to a specific MIDI device on the host OS.

Comment: thanks! After configuring the MPU-401, how do I decode the midi file and send it to the MPU-401?

Comment: To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.